Is the Language Lk={w∈(0+1)∗ ∣ value2(w) ≤ k} Regular for Any Arbitrary k?
Given the language Lk={w∈(0+1)∗∣value2(w)≤k}, which represents all binary strings w such that their numerical value in base 2 is less than or equal to k, is Lk​ regular for any k?
I am trying to understand the regularity of this language. Any insights or formal proofs would be greatly appreciated!
I've thought that I have to apply the Pumping Lemma but I don't know how to formalize it.

If you consider only proper binary encoding (meaning either $0$ or beginning with a $1$), then the language is finite, hence regular.
If not, the language is $0^*$ concatenated with the previous one, hence regular.

yes, I can see the intuition but I don't know how to formalize it

What is there to formalize?
